# Nginx url port appears

Tags: php, nginx, https, port, termux

I hosted a website using php-fpm and nginx on Termux and everytime I type the url localhost/sth and it redirects to localhost:8443/sth ,I don't want to see the port 8443, how to solve it?

Type url localhost/something and it redirects to localhost:8443/something

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You should investigate your `nginx.conf` file, it probably has some misconfiguration:

1. Open the nginx configuration file located at /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
   Locate the server block that contains the localhost:8443 server name, and change it to localhost
2. In the same server block, locate the listen directive and change the port number from 8443 to 80 (the default port for HTTP)
3. Save the changes and restart the nginx service using the command "service nginx restart"
4. Open your browser and try accessing the website using the localhost/sth URL. It should no longer redirect to localhost:8443/sth.